# A question regarding exchanging the limits

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on $X$ that converge a.e. on $X$ to $f$. Also, suppose $f \geq f_n$ a.e. for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that 
$$\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X f_n d\mu = \int_X f d\mu$$

The following is my proof.

Proof: By Fatou's Lemma,
$$\int_X f \leq \liminf \int_X f_n$$

Now, given
\begin{align} f_n &\leq f \quad \text{a.e} \\ \implies f_n &\leq f \quad \text{a.e} \quad \forall n \geq k \\ \implies \int_X f_n &\leq \int_X f \\ \implies \underset{n\geq k}{\text{sup}} \int_X f_n &\leq \int_X f \\ \implies \displaystyle \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \underset{n\geq k}{\text{sup}} \int_X f_n &\leq \int_X f \\ \implies \limsup \int_X f_n &\leq \int_X f
\end{align}

Hence, it is done.

I am confused whether it is correct.

Comment: It is 100% percent correct!